# how to select all records with every 15 minutes interval

Tags: mysql

My database updates every 1 minute of data but i need to display every 15 minutes data. how to select all records with 15 minutes data. if data starts from 07:00 so i need 07:15,07:30,07:45 like this.

```
17:00   107.11  107.50  
16:45   106.98  107.39
16:30   106.58  106.97
16:15   106.65  107.04
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any queries posted...

Comment: Something like `WHERE MINUTE(timeData) % 15 = 0`?

Comment: Thank you @Rocket hazmat it works select * from rpi_daten_neu where datum= (select max(datum) from rpi_daten_neu) and zeit >= '03:00:00' and zeit <= '23:46:00' and MINUTE(zeit) % 15 = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is saved in a `TIME` or `DATE` field, then you can get the "minute" value using the `MINUTE()` function.  Then you can check if that value is divisible by 15.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE MINUTE(timeData) % 15 = 0
```

Comment: Hello Rocket, can i get only hours and minutes from this timedata.

Comment: @Urock: There's an `HOUR()` function, as well as the `MINUTE()` function I show.  Check here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html